# DialogFragment doesn't show when set onDismiss

Tags: android, dialog

```
mSomeFragment = new SomeFragment();
mSomeFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "some");
```

The Fragment shows fine.

```
mSomeFragment = new SomeFragment();
mSomeFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "some");

mSomeFragment.onDismiss(new DialogInterface() {

     @Override
     public void cancel() {
          //
     }

     @Override
     public void dismiss() {
          //
     }
});
```

But when I set `onDismiss`, this doesn't work (the Fragment doesn't shows). I wanna do some operations when the dialog dismisses.
Could you tell me why??

Answer (score 1):

Calling onDismiss actually calls this code

```
  if (mDialog != null) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog = null;
  }
```

which dismisses the dialog. If you want to listen for events on the dialog use onOptionsItemSelected()